# Measuring flash-drive performance for portable apps?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, portable-apps

I recently bought a flash drive (Sandisk extreme SD in a USB 3 card reader) to run Cygwin off of so I can develop wherever. Benchmarks ranked it highly, but there's visible lag whenever I interact with it (ex, run cat through cygwin terminal). This got me thinking that traditional benchmarks may not be the best for portable apps, but google searches came up empty.

What benchmarks should I consider in a flash drive for portable apps?

Comment: Is it slow on multiple systems, or one system in particular?

Comment: It lags on multiple systems.

Comment: And what kind of speeds were you seeing on benchmark tests?